# bytes32 is not implicitly convertible

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

I am getting some errors related to bytes32. I tried to use the casting but it is not solving the proble.
My code is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.6.0;

    contract peInKSub{
      bytes32 [] m_pendingIndex ; 
      struct pendingConfirmation{
         bytes32 index;
         uint yetNeeded;
         bytes32 pendingOp;
      }
    
      pendingConfirmation pending;
    
      function confirmAndCheck ( bytes32 _operation )public returns ( bool ) { 
        pending.pendingOp = m_pendingIndex [ _operation ];
        // if we 're not yet working on this operation ,
        // switch over and reset the confirmation status .
        if ( pending . yetNeeded == 0) { 
          pending . index =  m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ++;
          //m_pendingIndex [ pending . index ] = _operation ;
        }//if
      }//fun
    }//contract
```

My error messages are:

> > solc prg46.sol prg46.sol:14:38: Error: Type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256. pending.pendingOp =
> > m_pendingIndex [ _operation ];
> > ^--------^ prg46.sol:18:35: Error: Type bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to expected type
> > uint256. pending . index =  m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ++;
> > ^--------^ prg46.sol:18:20: Error: Expression has to be an lvalue. pending . index =
> > m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ++;
> > ^---------------------------------^ prg46.sol:18:20: Error: Type uint8 is not implicitly convertible to
> > expected type bytes32. pending . index =  m_pendingIndex[_operation] .
> > length ++;
> > ^------------------------------------^

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

---

Comment: How big do you anticipate m_pendingIndex to be?

Answer (score 0):

```
m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ++
```

That variable is `bytes32` as defined here:

```
bytes32 [] m_pendingIndex ;
```

As such, it is 32 bytes long and the length cannot the adjusted. You seem to be trying to increase it but that is not possible.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry I am still getting the same errors:              >solc prg46.sol
prg46.sol:14:38: Error: bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to  uint256.
pending.pendingOp = m_pendingIndex [ _operation ];
                                     ^--------^
:18:35: Error:  bytes32 is not implicitly convertible to  uint256.
pending . index =  m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ;
                                  ^--------^
18:20: Error:  uint8 is not implicitly convertible to  bytes32.
pending . index =  m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ;
                   ^---------------------------------^

Comment: I removed the '++' from  m_pendingIndex[_operation] . length ++, but still I am getting the same errors as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are casting the length, which is uint to bytes32.  Did you try wrapping the length operation in abi.encodePacked()?